# Show/Hide div based on attribute value(checkbox value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

Is there any helper method available which shows/hides specified div based on the value of a model attribute?

Here is the partial where I want to show div that wraps `openid_domain_name` text field if `openid_enabled` is `true` and hide otherwise while editing record.

```
<%= form_for @application do |f| %>
    <%= render "shared/error_messages", target: @application %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </p>   
    <p>
      <%= f.check_box :openid_enabled %>
      <%= f.label 'openid', 'OpenID' %>
      <div id="application_openid_domain" style="display: none;">
        <%= f.label :openid_domain_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :openid_domain_name %>
      </div>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the javascript that shows/hides the div when user checks/unchecks the check box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $(':checkbox').click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $("#application_openid_domain").show();
          else
            $("#application_openid_domain").hide();            
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDITED**
Generated HTML Source:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/applications" class="new_application" id="new_application" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Cq2rYF1qkjnsobimMTAUvle9Hi82LwdvghcVWRtC/I0=" /></div>
  <p>
    <label for="application_name">Name</label>
    <input id="application_name" name="application[name]" size="30" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="application_description">Description</label>
    <input id="application_description" name="application[description]" size="30" type="text" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="application[openid_enabled]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="application_openid_enabled" name="application[openid_enabled]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <label for="application_openid">OpenID</label>
    <div id="application_openid_domain" style="display: none;">
      <label for="application_openid_domain_name">Openid domain name</label>
      <input id="application_openid_domain_name" name="application[openid_domain_name]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </p>
  <p><input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Application" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $(':checkbox').click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $("#application_openid_domain").show();
          else
            $("#application_openid_domain").hide();            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could I ask you to post the rendered (or a sample of the rendered) HTML that's seen by your browser? The server-side script is entirely irrelevant to your question and simply serves to make answering more difficult.

Comment: Added generated HTML in the question

Comment: Is it that you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/hK2dJ/

Comment: @CharlesJourdan Client side is fine. I want to achive it from server side.

Comment: In fact you want a checkbox which is not affected by the refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written custom helper to do the same. Please suggest if it is correct solution or not.

**app/helper/application_helper.rb**

```
def show_hide(show)
  show ? 'block' : 'none'
end
```

**app/views/applications/_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="application_openid_domain" style="display: <%= show_hide(@application.openid_enabled?)%>;">
  <%= f.label :openid_domain_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :openid_domain_name %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`jQuery.toggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

**HTML:**

```
​<div id="div">123</div>
<input type="checkbox" vlalue="show-hide" checked="checked" id="box">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#box').change(function() {
    $('#div').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/DZP2h/)

Comment: This looks more elegant but I want to show hide div before the rails server returns html.

Comment: If any logic can be performed on client and it's safe, than it's better to perform it there to offload the server (save such resources as memory, processing time and sometimes network bandwidth). The concept is each of 10 clients can do safe 1x work for itself instead of make server doing 10x work (for each of 10 clients). It's why we can see so much client-side MVC frameworks in these latter days.